# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. I used varchar data type and trying to insert 18-24 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have table

```
name    |datatype    
uid     |int           
name    |varchar(50)    
email   |varchar(32)    
pass    |varchar(32)    
about   |varchar(100)   
age     |varchar(20)    
gender  |varchar(50)    
address |varchar(100)   
phno    |numeric(18, 0)  
style   |varchar(30)
```

I give varchar data type to age field and trying to insert 18-24 value, so it's showing me error like this --

> "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

```
cnn.Open(); 
cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblregister set name='"+txtname .Text +"', pass='"+txtpass .Text +"',about='"+txtabout .Text +"', age='"+drpage.SelectedItem.Text +"', gender='"+rd .SelectedValue +"', address='"+txtadd .Text +"', phno='"+txtphno.Text +"' where email='"+Session ["user"]+"' ", cnn); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
cnn.Close();
```

what should I do?

Comment: can you please show your code ?

Comment: cnn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblregister set name='"+txtname .Text +"', pass='"+txtpass .Text +"',about='"+txtabout .Text +"', age='"+drpage.SelectedItem.Text  +"', gender='"+rd .SelectedValue +"', address='"+txtadd .Text +"', phno='"+txtphno.Text  +"' where email='"+Session ["user"]+"' ", cnn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   
        cnn.Close();

Comment: Edit your question to include the code please

Comment: Do you know what an SQL injection attack is?

Comment: Please do not add to your question in the comments. Add the code you provided in the question itself by using the edit feature.

Comment: Your selected item has text "18-24"? That cannot be converted to an numeric value. No way. What you can do is to save "18" (or any value you like) and translate it later to whatever you want (18-24 e.g.). The better way would be a extra table for the ages and join via an id.

Answer (score 1):

Your table column `phno` is `numeric` and you are saving data as `varchar`..
Also always use parameterised query to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

try below code

```
 cnn.Open(); 
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update tblregister set name=@name,pass=@pass,about=@about,
age=@age,gender=@gender,address=@address,phno=@phonenum where email = @email",cnn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname .Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass .Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@about", txtabout .Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", drpage.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rd .SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtadd .Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenum",Convert.ToInt64(txtphno.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session ["user"].ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Sachu.. Your code is not working.. It's showing error--> "The parameterized query '(@name nvarchar(5),@pass nvarchar(4000),@about nvarchar(3),@age ' expects the parameter '@email', which was not supplied."

Comment: Check `Session["user"]` Value and also Do `Session ["user"].ToString()` and add `@` before each value like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname .Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass .Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Little bit modification on Sachu's Answer

```
 cnn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update tblregister set name=@name,pass=@pass,about=@about,
    age=@age,gender=@gender,address=@address,phno=@phonenum where email = @email",cnn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname .Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass .Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@about", txtabout .Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", drpage.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rd .SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtadd .Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenum",Convert.ToInt64(txtphno.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session ["user"].ToString());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: KanisXXX still error-- "Input string was not in a correct format.", error is on -- "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenum",Convert.ToInt64(txtphno.Text));"

Comment: What are the value of txtphno.Text..??

Comment: This error is occurs when your input string is not convertible into Numeric , other cases if its getting white-space then you use `.Trim()` method to remove white-space ,See updated Answer.

Comment: hey @Lahar , i advice you to set the breakpoints and debug the code , and check what Value is txtphon is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 cnn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update tblregister set name=@name,pass=@pass,about=@about,
    age=@age,gender=@gender,address=@address,phno=@phno where email = @email",cnn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname .Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass .Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@about", txtabout .Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", drpage.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rd .SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtadd .Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phno",Convert.ToInt64(txtphno.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session ["user"].ToString());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Replace phonenum to phno